# Show that Y is a Gaussian process

Tags: time-series, gaussian

I have a Moving Average of order $q$. That is to say $MA(q)$.

Answer (score 1):

Possibly the fastest way is to use the direct definition.

Consider the set $$\{Y_{t_1},...,Y_{t_n}\}$$

We need to show that every linear combination of this set is Gaussian random variable. Take now such linear combination and denote the chosen indecies as in set $A$

$$\sum_{k\in A} \lambda_k Y_{t_k}$$

But what do we have here? A sum of sum of Gaussian variables times constants. And we know that is Gaussian by basic theorem. Hence we are done.

EDIT: To use the theorem that sums of Gaussians are Gaussian, we need that the Gaussians are independent. Let's show why that is. Consider $Y_{t_i},Y_{t_j}$ and show that the sum is indeed Gaussian using the moment generating function. Say that $t_i\leq t_j=t_i+n$

$$E(e^{s(Y_{t_i}+Y_{t_i+n})})=E(e^{s(\sum_{k=0}^q\theta_kZ_{t_i-k}+\sum_{k=0}^q\theta_kZ_{t_i+n-k})})$$

$$=E(e^{s(\sum_{k=0}^{q-n-1}Z_{t_i+n+k}(\theta_k+\theta_{k+n})+\sum_{k=0}^{\min(n-1,q)}\theta_{k} Z_{t_i+k}+\theta_{q-n+1+k} Z_{t_i+q+1+k})})$$

$$=\prod_{k=0}^{q-n-1} E(e^{s(Z_{t_i+n+k}(\theta_k+\theta_{k+n}))})\prod_{k=0}^{\min(n-1,q)}E(e^{s(\theta_{k} Z_{t_i+k})})
\prod_{k=0}^{\min(n-1,q)}E(e^{s(\theta_{q-n+1+k} Z_{t_i+q+1+k})})$$

And this is a product of MGTs of Gaussian variables, hence the sum is Gaussian. It remains to note that sums of  $Y$ are always in this form.

Comment: I have done this, but unfortunately my supervisor said that "It is not enough" to prove that Y is a Gaussian processes and thus I really don't know how I can proceed further with this :( I have literary searched in so many books and the only definition/theorem is the one you also gave me. Is there any other way to make this proof more solid?

Comment: Thank you very much. I will closely look at this proof and try to understand. It was certainly more complicated than I thought. So this is the complete proof then? What happens in the 3rd equation from above? And MGT? Do you mean MGF = Moment Generating Function? Thanks alot!!

Comment: @GAUSS It is "complete", however could still be more rigorous since we only proved sum of any two variables is Gaussian. In 3rd equation we notice that $e^{a+b}=e^ae^b$, and since the variables were independent we can pull the product out of the expectation.

Comment: Big thanks mate! Been stuck on this for a while. You made my day :)

Comment: @Gauss No problem, anyway it should be enough that $\sum Y_i = \sum a_i Z_i$, and note that $Z_i$ are independent Gaussian, then the result indeed follows. The moment generating function is not necessary for this proof.

Comment: Hmm, okay. But the part under "Edit" must be included i guess? What do you denote by "MGT"?

Comment: @GAUSS As long as you can show that the sum of $Y$s is a sum of $Z$s you are fine.